# Регистрация по феншую

Tags: php

Есть `index.php`. Форма регистрации находится на главной странице.

1. Если сделать обработчик в этом же файле `action="index.php"`, то в принципе все нормально, за исключением одной вещи. При нажатии "зарегистрироваться" в адресе появляется `сайт.ком/index.php`. Это мне не нравится. Подумал .htaccess решит проблему... `index.php` больше не видно. Но так почему-то не работает обработчик. Почему?
2. Если обработчик сделать в другом файле, например `registr.php` и потом перенапрявлять пользователя, то я не знаю как выводить ошибки в `index.php` из этого обработчика. А также не знаю, как передавать валидные данные обратно в форму, чтобы они не сбрасывались. Через `value="<?php echo $_POST[firstname]?>` получается только если обработчик и форма находятся вместе. Если обработчик в другом файле, то после возврата назад `header('Location: /');` ничего не сохраняется.

Comment: Поставьте в форме `action="/"`, либо вообще уберите этот атрибут

Comment: хоспади, как всё просто =)))